# PNG to Monochrome Bitmap for Thermal Printer in PHP?

Tags: php, image-conversion, thermal-printer

I'm trying to dynamically generate QR codes for my thermal printer. In order to do this, I have to send a request to my server (say something like http://domain.example.com/qr?url=).

This page should then go and get a QR code from Google in PNG format. So far so good.

But now the difficult part. Once I have done that, I need to convert it to something along the lines of [this](http://www.ladyada.net/images/thermalprinter/changeattrib.gif).

I have previously found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181614/how-to-convert-monochrome-image-to-bitwise-format-for-thermal-printer) question, but, unlike him, I need to do it on the web. I don't have access to installing PHP modules on the server, and so the best option for me, as far as I know, is [phMagik](http://www.francodacosta.com/phmagick), but again the problem is that as far as I know this does not support the extra parameters that can be fed into the normal Linux or Windows version of ImageMagik, as detailed on [this documentation page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#halftone).

So does anyone know how I could get round this problem? In the long term I'm hoping to make my own version of the [Little Printer](http://bergcloud.com/littleprinter/). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the normal linux version of ImageMagick - call it using `exec()`

If you don't have access to install things on your server, then it's going to get a little more complicated. If you have GD installed (you probably do), you can use http://php.net/imagecreatefrompng to get at the pixel data. You can then manually create the thing you're looking for, something like this:

```
$file = "/path/to/png.png"; 
$image = ImageCreateFromPng($file); 
list($w, $h) = GetImageSize($file); 

$pixels = array();
for ($x=0; $x<$w; $x++){
for ($y=0; $y<$h; $y++){
    $rgb = ImageColorAt($image, $x, $y); 
    $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
    $pixels = '0x'.sprintf('%02x', ($r+$g+$b)/3); # store the average of r/g/b
}
}

echo "static unsigned char __attribute__ ((progmem)) adalogo [] = {\n";
echo implode(', ', $pixels);
echo "};\n";
```

You need to first get the actual PNG - you could either fetch it via URL if you have file wrappers enabled:

```
$file = "http://url.com/to/png.png"; 
$image = ImageCreateFromPng($file);
```

Or use PHP on the command line first the grab the image:

```
$file = "/path/to/png.png"; 
exec("php /path/to/script.php > $file");
$image = ImageCreateFromPng($file);
```

Comment: I see where you're coming from - but surely to do this I have to have ImageMagick for Linux installed on my server, and I'm afraid I can't to that because I'm on a shared hosting service. Any ways around that?

Comment: Updated my answer with a possible solution

Comment: There seems to be a problem - I'm generating the image dynamically in another file (it's a QR Code), outputting a header as `image/png`, but in the file that runs this code, it says it's not a valid PNG. How would I get around this?

Comment: Upload the file somewhere and link it here - i'll try and figure out what the file format is

Comment: It's [here](http://dog.alexforey.com/printability/bookmarks/qr) (where I'm outputting the converted file) and [here](http://dog.alexforey.com/printability/bookmarks/rawqr) (where It's being generated)

Comment: aha! it's loading the php rather than the png. updated the answer to include some possible solutions